# Did Dwight Eisenhower say "Never let yourself be persuaded that any one Great Man, any one leader, is necessary to the salvation of America"?

Tags: quotes

“Never let yourself be persuaded that any one Great Man, any one leader, is necessary to the salvation of America. When America consists of one leader and 158 million followers, it will no longer be America.”

The quote above is attributed to Dwight Eisenhower, the 34th president of the United States. However, I can't find where the quote comes from, such as a speech or a book. I've tried searching the quote, but all I could find were websites sharing quotes or people quoting it, the latter only stating the quote is from Eisenhower and not when or where he said it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for the author of an extended quote. Perhaps this belongs on History.

Comment: After searching the term "quote" in both History and English Language & Usage, I think you're right. However, when I was looking for which Stack Exchange would be best before asking this question, the term "quote," the results were either related to coding or was related to a specific type of person that Eisenhower wasn't, such at mathematicians or aviators, and after taking a look at the different Stack Exchanges available, I thought that this would be the right place. It turns out I was wrong, but I got the answer I needed. At least now I know where to go next time I need a quote source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotation is from Eisenhower's "[An Open Letter to America's Students](http://www.2rbetter.org/archives/2008-04-05%20-%20Lincoln%27s%20Step-mother)" published in the October 1948 issue of *Reader’s Digest*. Eisenhower was then President of Columbia University.

> Never let yourself be persuaded that any one Great Man, any one
> leader, is necessary to the salvation of America. When America
> consists of one leader and 143,000,000 followers, it will no longer be
> America. Truly American leadership is not of any one man. It is of
> multitudes of men—and women.

Comment: Not a question for ELU.